# JVM 6.0_30-b12 crashed after our product upgrade

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-crash

We have recently upgraded our product from earlier version at site.
And after the upgrade when we try to bring the service, it failed to come with the following jvm error.

We have verified the jvm options also and it looks same as old product version.

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:InitialHeapSize=2147483648 -XX:MaxHeapSize=2147483648     -XX:ParallelGCThreads=18 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC

-------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002af63ec7d90e, pid=19274, tid=1092286784
#
# JRE version: 6.0_30-b12
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.5-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x50f90e]  unsigned+0xce
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /apps/hs_err_pid19274.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#
```

I tried google it but couldn't gte much info.

Can you please help me to check and solve this issue?

Comment: What's in the /apps/hs_err_pid19274.log file ?

Answer (score 0):

Java 6 is end-of-life. You are throwing away engineering time by trying to upgrade to a new Java 6 version at this time.

Move to Java 7 - Java 6 is a critical production risk for several reasons these days and you should upgrade, without exception.